# iOS Development: How can I animate the addition/removal of form controls in a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have a login view with username & password textfields and two buttons for "sign in" and "create new account".  Currently, I have it so that if the user clicks the "create new account" button, it loads a new view with the same controls, except the "sign in" button is removed and a "confirm password" text field is added.  Is is possible to add/remove these controls to the same view instead of loading a new view?  If so, is it possible to animate this as well?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a simple UIView animation. I don't think you can animate `addSubview:` or `removeFromSuperview:` but you can animate changes in alpha:

```
// add confirmPasswordButton to the view, alpha=0 (invisible)
[confirmPasswordButton setAlpha:0.0];
[self.view addSubview:confirmPasswordButton];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"switchButtons" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[confirmPasswordButton setAlpha:1.0];
[signinButton setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Those are the basics. Check out Apple's docs for more details on callbacks, using blocks, more animation parameters, etc:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make them animate in however you want. Take a look at block animations in UIView. Most properties can be animated such as frame and alpha.